# Remove string from a string jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I am trying to replace within a string using jquery

```
var myString ="qwerty"

var avoid ="t"
```

I want to do someting like

```
myString.replace(avoid,'');
```

I was able to remove like `myString.replace('t','');` But i want it to be like `myString.replace(avoid,'');`

How to do it?

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nKSZT/

Comment: Have you tried running this code?

Comment: Yes no error. But its not getting replaced

Comment: I have tried running it

Comment: You should store the replaced value, `replace` doesn't change the `myString` variable's value.

Comment: @undefined: You are right man. Sorry my mistake It worked. http://jsfiddle.net/nKSZT/1/

Comment: this should work. the only problem i see is your spelling when you declare var mystring it is all small later. but when you are replacing you are using capital "S" in myString.

Comment: Note that simply passing a string (or a variable containing a string) to `replace` will only replace the *first* occurrence. You'll need a Regex if you want to replace all occurrences of "t" or whatever.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your problem is that `replace` does not replace the characters in your original string but returns a new string with the replacement.

```
myString = myString.replace(avoid,'');
```

Answer (score 9):

`replace` does not modify the string, it *returns a modified* string. So do:

```
 var avoided = myString.replace(avoid,'');
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/MBjy3/1/

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 var myString = "qwerty";
 alert(myString);
 var avoid = "t";
 var abc=myString.replace(avoid, '');
 alert(abc);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nKSZT/2/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "send_more_id4";
alert(str);
var res = str.replace("send_more_id", ""); 
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, there is another approach:

```
var myString ="qwerty",
    avoid = "t";

var result = myString.split(avoid).join('');

console.log(result);
```